# Too many unecessary events

Tags: projection, event-sourcing

I'm new to eventsourced apps and since the beginning I'm facing an issue that I'm unsure how to resolve.

I work in ecommerce and I always try to convey meaningful events to my aggregates like `PriceIncreasedEvent`, `ProductDeactivatedEvent`, `OutOfStockEvent` etc

But many times I just want to do a simple "CRUD" style with my aggregate. For instance, the user can change the product image, but I don't want to mess with my aggregate with `ImageUploadedEvent` event, since it isn't part of the domain its supposed to handle.

All I want to do is simply set the new image path in the database. But since "projections" are supposed to be disposable, I can't do that, because I would loose information.

This often happens with other types of editorial data, like the title/name of something. I don't want to create a event `TitleChanged`, I know that's a code smell, it doesn't matter for the domain that the `TitleChanged`. I just want to change it.

Maybe eventsourcing was a bad idea? How do you guys handle these kind of scenarios?

Answer (score 2):

Something to consider reading up on is Context Mapping from Domain-driven Design.

I agree with VoiceOfUnreason that you can absolutely mix traditional CRUD with Event Sourcing in a system - and probably should.

Something that was an eye-opener for me was the understanding that the same concept in the domain can exist and solve different problems in different contexts. Event Sourcing can be suitable for modeling one part and CRUD could be more suitable for another. You can think of it as two separate systems that solves different parts of the whole.

An example could be a Product with your PriceIncreasedEvent etc, but there can also be a *different* Product entity which is CRUD-based - containing the base data such as the product title and images, which solves that problem. It's all about how much you care about tracking the state changes and if the changes (events) themselves are important to your domain.

I've usually merged these together in a query-service (CQRS-style) and used a UUID to key the aggregate together with the CRUD entity.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

> Maybe eventsourcing was a bad idea?

Event sourcing is is a golf club, not a pool cue -- you aren't required to use it for every shot.

In particular, if you don't need the capability to recover the model as of some arbitrary point in the past, event sourcing may not end up pulling its full weight.

> For instance, the user can change the product image, but I don't want to mess with my aggregate with ImageUploadedEvent event, since it isn't part of the domain its supposed to handle.

Right - and it's not like you are going to have a lot of complex domain logic around the contents of the product image, or even the spelling of the URL/file path that gives you access to the image.  It's just a big opaque blob of data.

Event sourcing makes less sense for that case than it does for complex business capabilities where your company is deriving its competitive advantage.

Good news though: there's no rule that says that you have to use event sourcing everywhere.  You can pick and choose.

(There are, however, some complications in trying to use one transaction to update two different databases.)